# How to use gitignore to only commit/add the highest number directory from collection of numbered directories

Tags: git, bash, scripting

I am using Github and openFoam (an open source cfd solver package). The results from the solver are stored in numbered directories which correspond to their simulation time step. These results folders can be large, and I don't want most of them on Github anyways, as they are not particularly useful.

I would, however, like to have the latest time step uploaded as it is the final result. The problem is that for every simulation the total amount of time to find that final solution may vary so I can't just use a static number

e.g.

```
!10000/
```

in my `.gitignore`. Can I incorporate Bash scripting or anything else in my ignore file to find the highest numbered directory and only keep it?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the whole list of directories in descending order and get the 1st line, negate that and put it into gitignore.

```
$ mkdir 110
$ mkdir 120
$ mkdir 200
$ ls
110  120  200
$ ls -1 | sort -nr | head -1
200
$ echo "!"$(ls -1 | sort -nr | head -1)"/"
!200/
$ echo "!"$(ls -1 | sort -nr | head -1)"/" > .gitignore
$ cat .gitignore 
!200/
```